# Using decay with perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming, visual-studio-2019

Assume we have 2 functions:

```
template <typename T> void callDecayExample1(T& t)
{
    std::initializer_list<T> testList2{ 1, 2, 3 };
}

template <typename T> void callDecayExample2(T&& t)
{
    std::initializer_list<std::decay_t<T>> testList{1, 2, 3};
}
```

and we call them like this:

```
const int& i = 2;
int j = 10;
int& ref_j = j;

callDecayExample1(i);       // deduced as const int&
callDecayExample1(ref_j);// deduced as int&
callDecayExample1(j);   // deduced as int&

callDecayExample2(i);       // deduced as const int&
callDecayExample2(ref_j);// deduced as int&
callDecayExample2(j);   // deduced as int&
```

depspite the similar deducing in both functions, in the 2nd function I have to use std::decay_t to compile the application. Why it is so?

I use Visual studio 2019 with the /std:c++17 flag

Comment: In the first case, `T` is non-referenced type, i.e., `int` or `const int` for the three cases.  In the second case `T`, can be a reference type, which makes the difference. You can compare `decltype(t)` and `T` to visualize this.

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry for that, corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a function like

```
template <typename T> void callDecayExample1(T& t)
{
    std::initializer_list<T> testList2{ 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

then `T` is only going to get deduced as a non reference type.  If you give it a `int&`, then `T` becomes `int` so that `t` becomes a `int&`.  Because of that you do not need to use `decay`.

In

```
template <typename T> void callDecayExample2(T&& t)
{
    std::initializer_list<std::decay_t<T>> testList{1, 2, 3};
}
```

If you pass a `int&` then `T` gets deduced as a `int&`, and then reference collapsing rules turn `int& &&` into `int&` for the type of `t`.  This means that without `decay` you would try to make a `std::initializer_list<int&>` which you can't do.

Comment: Reference collapsing, that's it!

Answer (score 3):

It is not correct to say that the deduced types are identical:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void printType()
{
  std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void callDecayExample1(T& t)
{
  printType<T>();
  std::initializer_list<T> testList2{1, 2, 3};
}

template <typename T>
void callDecayExample2(T&& t)
{
  printType<T>();
  std::initializer_list<std::decay_t<T>> testList{1, 2, 3};
}

int main()
{
  const int i = 0;
  int j = 1;
  int& ref_j = j;

  callDecayExample1(i);
  callDecayExample1(ref_j);
  callDecayExample1(j);

  callDecayExample2(i);
  callDecayExample2(ref_j);
  callDecayExample2(j);

  return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
void printType() [with T = const int]
void printType() [with T = int]
void printType() [with T = int]

void printType() [with T = const int&]
void printType() [with T = int&]
void printType() [with T = int&]
```

In your situation `std::decay` removes the extra reference that is present in the second example.

Comment: Yeah, or _ _FUNCSIG _ _ for MSVC

Answer (score 0):

Because `T` may or may not be a reference type:

```
template <typename T> void callDecayExample2(T&& t)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int&>::value)
        std::initializer_list<std::decay_t<T>> testList{ 1, 2, 3 };
    else
        std::initializer_list<T> testList{ 1, 2, 3 };
}

int val = 5;
callDecayExample2(5)   // T = int
callDecayExample2(val) // T = int&
```